# FontAwesome + IE7 + Dynamic Loading Content = Pain

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, font-awesome

I'm trying to use FontAwesome for some control icons on a jQuery lightbox plugin I've developed. For the life of me, and I can't get the icons to display in IE7. I followed the advised here to [reload the IE7 stylesheet](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/38#issuecomment-6621377) after the lightbox opens. However, where the icons should be, I just see their UTF numbers (e.g. `0xf024;`). It's almost as if the output has been "escaped" somehow. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
I just discovered that this isn't just happening on dynamically loaded content. I'm seeing the same thing on any icon just loaded in the HTML.

**Update 2:**
I think the problem may be related to subsetting. I was using a [subset of font-awesome](http://www.icnfnt.com/#/), and when I tried just loading the complete package it worked. Now, I have to see what the difference is between the subset and the full package that's breaking it.

Comment: Why [support the 4%](http://theie7countdown.com/)?

Comment: I'd love to drop IE7 support, but unfortunately my site gets more IE7 visitors than average. :(

Comment: What does your meta tag look like?

Comment: I'm assuming this is the one you're asking about:`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the update above, the problem was with the subsetting of the font. The customized IE7 stylesheet for the subset had a few bugs. The problem came from the characters being referenced like this `0xf023;` instead of like this `&#xf023;`. Once I made that correction, everything worked as expected.